# Update de uma única informação no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, sql-update

Estou começando a trabalhar com Laravel e queria saber se podem me ajudar.
Preciso atualizar um único valor no banco, usando 'nome' na cláusula where em vez de id.

Isso é para uma situação de um sistema real que preciso migrar para Laravel logo em seguida.

#### MODEL:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class teste extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'teste';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'nome',
        'verificado'
    ];
}
```

#### VIEW: - Envia post

```
@foreach($nomes as $nome)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="nome[]" value="{{ $nome->nome }}">
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

#### CONTROLLER:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\teste;
public function teste(Request $nome)
    {
        foreach ($nome->nome as $nome) {
            teste::table('teste')
                ->where('nome', $nome)
                ->update(['verificado' => 1]);

            Depois do update, a variável $nome é usada para tratar um arquivo xml bem aqui logo em seguida...
        }
    }
```

Ele me devolve o erro: ***Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()***

Tenho certeza que esta sintaxe do meu update está errada, mas infelizmente ainda não consegui compreender na documentação a forma correta.

O update só precisa mudar verificado de NULL para 1 e o dado é único, não há como existir dois nomes iguais neste sistema.

Além disso, a variável $nome é utilizada logo em seguida para tratar um xml salvo em pasta (selecionando o arquivo etc). a função que trata o xml funciona perfeitamente sem problemas, por isso não coloquei aqui. Esse verificado é só uma informação para o usuário informando que alguém já trabalhou nele.

Comment: Seu código esta muito errado e vc não deve fazer assim que é diferente poder fazer. Pode acontecer nomes iguais e isso já vai dar problema o seu foreach você sobreescreve a variável do Request, então tudo precisa ser repensado.

Comment: Olá amigo, este código é o início de um teste, ainda será melhorado e tratado como deve ser feito até chegar em prod! Obrigado, abraços!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você não precisa chamar novamente o nome da tabela.

```
teste::where('nome', $nome)->update(['verificado' => 1]);
```

[Veja mais informações na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#updates)

Comment: Valeu, resolvido. Na verdade, logo em seguida apareceu o seguinte erro:

"Laravel:Unknown column 'updated_at'"

Pesquisando na internet rapidamente, se resolveu com este tópico:

https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277955/laravelunknown-column-updated-at&xid=25657,15700019,15700124,15700149,15700186,15700191,15700201&usg=ALkJrhizVyVyBDJ77sFcG0AT33SL590Ojw

Obrigado!!